# Set matrix values to zero with "multiplication"

Tags: matrices

Is there a standard matrix operation that multiplies the elements of each matrix together based only on their position?  For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\end{pmatrix}\ast\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 3\\0 & 5 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Yes!  That's it! Make it an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I already did ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), which is different from the usual matrix product.