# what is the name of a regular (column * column) product of a vector

Tags: vectors, terminology, products

Let $A = |a_{0},a_{1}, a_{2},... a_{n} |$ and $B = |b_{0},b_{1}, b_{2},... b_{n}|$. If we define a vector function $product$ such that $product(A,B)=|(a_{0}b_{0}) , (a_{1}b_{1}) , (a_{2}b_{2}),\dots, (a_{n}b_{n}) |$, is there a standard name for a vector operation that is equivalent to $product(A,B)$?  In more simple words, has noone thought of defining an operation for a simple product between column values of a vector (what I like to call the excel product, hahaha), but there has been defined operations for things related to angles of vectors as products?  I searched a lot and didn't find anything about this.

Comment: Cf. [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)); cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508836/set-matrix-values-to-zero-with-multiplication)

Comment: The main reason this isn’t much discussed is that it isn’t so much a vector operation as it is a “block” operation. Vectors are not rows of numbers, they are geometric objects.

Comment: This is also called “component-wise multiplication” or “slot-wise multiplication” but Hadamard product is the formal name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product is a special case of the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of matrices.